# How to delete multiple rows in a table that are selected in a listbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, user-interface, listbox

I have a table which's content is displayed at listbox. I want to delete rows that user has selected. How to know which rows to delete and how delete?

This is how I display listbox items:

```
DataSet AllPairs = new DataSet();
AllPairs.ReadXml(PathToPairsXML);
listBox1.DataSource = AllPairs.Tables[0];
listBox1.ValueMember = "PAIR_text";
listBox1.DisplayMember = "PAIR_text";
```

Listbox selection property is MultiExtended.

Comment: You want to delete rows from the list box or from the underlying data table?

Comment: from an underlying table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `DataTable` as `DataSource` of your `ListBox`, items are of type [`DataRowView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview(v=vs.110).aspx), so you can use `Delete` method of `DataRowView` or using `Row` property of `DataRowView` access the row behind that data row view and remove that row from your `DataTable`.

You can use this code:

```
this.listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<DataRowView>()
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(item =>
    {
        //item.Delete(); 
        //or
        this.AllPairs.Tables[0].Rows.Remove(item.Row);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string  selectedtext= "";    
foreach (int i in listBox1 .SelectedIndices )
    {
       selectedtext= listBox1.Items[i].ToString ();

       DataRow[] drCollection=AllPairs.Tables[0].Select("PAIR_text='"+selectedtext+"'");

      if (drCollection.Length>0)
                AllPairs.Tables[0].Rows.Remove(drCollection[0]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is so far the simplest way:

```
var selectedRows = listBox1.SelectedItems.Cast<DataRowView>().ToList();
foreach (var dr in selectedRows)
    dr.Delete();
```

A small explanation. I'll be using the concrete types instead of `var` keyword for better understanding. The following line

```
listBox1.DataSource = AllPairs.Tables[0];
```

in equivalent to something like this

```
DataView dataView = AllPairs.Tables[0].DefaultView;
for (int i = 0; i < dataView.Count; i++)
{
    DataRowView dataRowView = dataView[i];
    listBox1.Items.Add(dataRowView);
}
```

Now when we know the list box contains `DataRowView` objects, although the `SelectedItems` returns items of type `object`, we can safely cast them back to a `DataRowView` and call `Delete` method.
But why we need `ToList` call? Because when we delete a row, the data source will send a notification to the list box and it will remove that item from the `Items` and `SelectedItems`. While it's not required, depending of the internal implementation this could destroy the selection. So in order to be absolutely sure that this will not happen, we buffer the initial selection in a list before proceeding with delete.